# ubuntu 16.10 (fresh install) system freezes on "Connecting Steam account: [name]"

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, steam, crash

I just did a fresh install of ubuntu 16.10. I installed nvidia-367 and nvidia-prime and installed all updates. After that I switched to intel graphics (hd 530 (skylake 6700HQ)) and installed steam. After steam was installed and updated I logged in and as soon as the screen "Connecting Steam account: [name]" shows up the systems freezes.
It works fine on nvidia graphics. I tried running steam from a terminal and the only error it shows is "Unable to remove /home/arno/.steam/CONFIG/SteamAppData.vdf!". Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

ps <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>prntscr</kbd>+REISUB doesn't do anything. It's a complete systems freeze.